# Hydrochloric acids inability to chlorinate cinnamyl alcohol on 2 sites

Tags: bond

According to a reference (J.  Am.  Chem.  SOC.  1985,  107,  2033-2046), cinnamyl chloride can be prepared in quantitative yield by the reaction of cinnamyl alcohol with hydrochloric acid. Looking at the structure, I can see that the hydroxy group will be chlorinated, but I do not understand why the delicate double bond will be left untouched?

Comment: Because it’s not really delicate in cinnamate.

Comment: Is there any literature describing why the bond on cinnamates is not delicate?

Comment: Not sure. But the key point is that the double bond participates in resonance both with the phenyl ring and the carboxy/$\ce{COCl}$ group making it part of one big pi system and rather unprone to traditional reactions of alkenes.

Comment: Thanks for the insight - add a reply to get the points for this one.